# Outputting the results from package bife to word

Tags: r, ms-word

I am currently working on some probit regressions with the life package.
Does anyone know how to export the outputs to word?
I am just running regressions like:

```
library(bife)

probLdbifea <- bife(Esieg ~ TTRverf + deltaTTR|spieler,
                    model = "probit", bias_corr = TRUE,
                    data = datregL)
```

and would like to export the output like it is possible with "stargazer" for "normal" regressions

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post a *reproducible example*. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I am just running regressions like: 
probLdbifea=bife(Esieg~TTRverf+deltaTTR|spieler,model="probit",bias_corr=TRUE, data = datregL)

and would like to export the output like it is possible with "stargazer" for "normal" regressions

Comment: You should edit the question with that information, it's more difficult to read code posted as comments. You can, for instance, take an example from the package's documentation and use it to ask the question.

Comment: Maybe `stargazer(summary(probLdbifea)$cm, type = "html", out = "bife.html")`.